# How to resize image like in google plus based on height and making it responsive

Tags: php, javascript, responsive-design, image-resizing, php-gd

I want to make an image scalable on web across all platforms and for all resolutions. I am pretty impressed by the way google does it. For example:

1900 - https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-9xyCVGjVJjE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAG0/a4jFEtQ3ziY/s1900-c-k-no/photo.jpg

190 - https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-9xyCVGjVJjE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAG0/a4jFEtQ3ziY/s190-c-k-no/photo.jpg

There are lot of resources on web that shows how to resize images based on screen size, but none come close to google plus. I got some links for the same question

[Google Script Image Resizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12152413/google-script-image-resizing),

[Resize image like google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329265/resize-image-like-google),

http://www.quora.com/Google+/How-google-resize-images-dynamically-based-on-screen-size

But none of the above solved my issue. I am able to re size an image but not able to make it responsive like in google plus.

I have knowledge on jquery, javascript, php. I beleive it is something to do with php gd library and jquery or maybe through css media queries, but not able to get through the problem. I have tried the following resources before putting up a question here:

1. http://adaptive-images.com/ - Unable to resize the image based on height. It scales well with respect to width.
2. http://boxresizer.com/
3. Timthumb : http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/projects/timthumb/ , http://www.darrenhoyt.com/2008/04/02/timthumb-php-script-released/ - This doesn't scale well with height.
4. Server side image resizer: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/server-side-image-resizer/
5. Css based resizing: http://blog.kurtschindler.net/post/flexible-dynamically-resizing-images-with-css

Can some one please suggest me to solve the issue or help me sorting my issue based on above resources.

Comment: I think the extension `.jpg` calls a server-side script (e.g. PHP) instead of the image directly. The Script generates a picture in the requested size.

htaccess example: `RewriteEngine on` `RewriteRule image.jpg image.php [R=301]`

Answer (score -1):

Ethan Marcott's solution is here.

http://unstoppablerobotninja.com/entry/fluid-images/

He is guy who first used the term "Responsive web design". Hope it solves your issue. Anyway a nice question for the age.